# Recording video report for protractor execution on a remote environment

Tags: selenium, ffmpeg, protractor

I am executing my protractor test suite from my desktop and I am using a remote selenium server. I have configured the 'protractor-video-reporter' to capture execution for my local windows environment (using ffmpeg codec) and when I execute using my local selenium server, the video capture works fine. But when I execute on remote VMs, it captures my desktop screen.
I understand that I need to provide the remote location path to ffmpeg codec, but I do not know how to provide appropriate user credentials so that my automation can invoke the remote plugin?
My present configuration is as follows:

```html
const VideoReporter = require('protractor-video-reporter');
...
let config = {
...
 onPrepare: () => {
 ...
 VideoReporter.prototype.jasmineStarted = function () {
   var self = this;
   if (self.options.singleVideo) {
    var videoPath = path.join(self.options.baseDirectory, 'protractor-specs.mpg');
    self._startScreencast(videoPath);
    if (self.options.createSubtitles) {
     self._subtitles = [];
     self._jasmineStartTime = new Date();
    }
   }
 };
 ...
 jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new VideoReporter({
 baseDirectory: './test-output/videoreport',
 createSubtitles: false,
 saveSuccessVideos: true,
 singleVideo: true,
 ffmpegCmd: "C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", /*Probably some changes needed here*/
 ffmpegArgs: [
    '-f', 'gdigrab',
    '-framerate', '30',
    '-video_size', 'wsxga',
    '-i', 'desktop',
    '-q:v', '10',
 ]
}));
 ...
  }
  ...
}
export { config };
```

Considering that execution and video capture both has to happen in remote server, please suggest a suitable solution.

Comment: I think it's no way to capture the brower on remote machine,  I think `protractor-video-reporter` can only capture the desktop on where your executing  script  inside.  Thinking about your script run on your local machine, so the `protractor-video-reporter` also run on your local, then it will invoke the `ffmpeg.exe` to capture the screen. so it must require `ffmpeg.exe` should also be on the same machine (your local machine).  If so, how `ffmpeg.exe` can capture remote machine screen if `ffmpeg.exe` not install on remote machine.  Maybe my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I completely agree with you. And my question is even if I install ffmpeg.exe in my remote, how can I use that to capture execution report in the remote machine?

Comment: Hi @DebasishMukherjee, 
by any chance did you happen to figure this one out?